# (Qt) Making a combobox delegate show as options a whole column of a model

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, delegates

Well, this question may be done due to my poor understanding of the job of the delegates.

Using the model/view framework. I have made several derived delegates till now, but what I need right now is to get a select-option-delegate (for example a combobox) to show as options the data saved on a column of my QTableModel I select. I'm not being able to do this, since (I think) while reimplementing, the arguments of the functions, doesn't contain the whole model but only the item of the QTableModel.

I don't know how to fill the delegate's editor with the data of the model column. I think this can't be done due to safety issues on programming, I have tried to send a signal from the delegate asking for the model, but it appears that delegates cannot emit signals.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

I have looked at a combobox delegate with custom options example that is around but that one does not read the options from a model, the options are loaded as constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you created a new class derived from `QStyledItemDelegate` or `QAbstractItemDelegate` you can create a new `constructor` and pass there a pointer to a model or whatever you want.

2.Also you can use methods of `QModelIndex` to get any data from a model. For example: `index.data()` will return a data to display, `index.data(Qt::UserRole)` will return anything you implemented it in `data` method of a model. Example:

```
 virtual QVariant MyMode::data (const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
 {
    if (role == Qt::UserRole)
      return m_options;
    ...
 }

 QWidget *StyledItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
 {
     Options options = index.data(Qt::UserRole).value<Options>()
     ...
 }
```

Comment: 1. So after the class MyCustomDelegate is created on the constructor of my main widget should appear:

model = new QSqlTablemodel;
view = new QTableModel;
MyCustomDelegate *mydelegate = new MyCustomDelegate(model);

view->setdelegateforcolumn(mydelegate,column);
.
.
2. Are you saying that I can create an UserRole so data is able to return me instread of the data of the item, the data of the whole column where the item is set?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user2348235 1 - yes. 2 - yes. What is returned by `UserRole` depends on you. In my example it returns some options independently of what column is. You can add a check `if (role == Qt::UserRole and index.column() == 0` or `switch(index.column()) case 0: return settingsA; case 1: return settingsB;...`.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, after a lot of coding and having a bad time making the classes work. I have find that there is a widget that already does autocompletion while searching matches on a model you select. The class is called QCompleter...